# Make fields conditionally required

Tags: conditional, custom-field, required

Is there a way to make fields conditionally required?

[image: Example of fields]

I have a toggle field that is used to hide or show a section (see screenshot: "Section 3 enabled"). If the section is shown (toggle: on), the fields need to be filled. If the section is hidden (toggle: off), the  fields can be left empty.
Note that the section's fields can be of any type (text, matrix, entry, assets, ...).

I already tried the plugin [Reasons](https://github.com/mmikkel/Reasons-Craft), and unfortunately it's not what I need because it will still return a validation error for the hidden but required fields.

My Craft CMS version is 2.6.2983.

Answer (score 1):

There is currently not a native way to do this in Craft. You should consider adding a thumbs-up/comment to [this feature request](https://github.com/craftcms/cms/issues/805) if you'd like to see it, though.